# Apache Tomcat SSL Configuration

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl

I am trying to configure SSL onn apache Tomcat Java Servlet application working on Unix but have had no luck despite many attempts and trying to find the answer on the web. Can anyone help please. I did the following action:

Generate a Java keystore and key pair

```
 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/bin/keytool -genkey -v -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat
-keypass changeit -storepass changeit -keystore /mykeystore/keystore.jks -keysize 2048
```

Generate a certificate signing request

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/bin/keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat -file
/mykeystore/tomcat.csr -storepass changeit -keystore /mykeystore/keystore.jks
```

Import a root and intermediate CA certificate

```
vi /mykeystore/root.crt

/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/bin/keytool -import -alias root  -trustcacerts -file
/mykeystore/root.crt -keystore /mykeystore/keystore.jks

vi /mykeystore/tomcat.crt

/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/bin/keytool -import -alias tomcat -file /mykeystore
/tomcat.crt -keystore /mykeystore/keystore.jks
```

Update server.xml

```
<-- Define a SSL Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 -->
<!--
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
       maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="/mykeystore/keystore.jks" keystorePass="changeit"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Restart Tomcat

```
service apache2 restart
```

I get the error:

Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
24-May-2012 20:54:10 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/i386/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
24-May-2012 20:54:11 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
24-May-2012 20:54:12 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init

```
SEVERE: Error initializing endpoint
java.io.IOException: jsse.invalid_ssl_conf

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.checkConfig(JSSESocketFactory.java:846)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.init(JSSESocketFactory.java:522)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.createSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:156)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:538)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:176)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1022)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:703)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:838)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:538)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:562)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: No available certificate or key corresponds to the SSL
cipher suites which are enabled.

at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.checkEnabledSuites(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:310)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.accept(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:255)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.checkConfig(JSSESocketFactory.java:842)
... 15 more
```

24-May-2012 20:54:12 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initialize

Please Help. Many Thanks.

Comment: Well, not sure if you were able to pinpoint the error, but this is a good starting point to dig deeper:
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: No available certificate or key corresponds to the SSL
cipher suites which are enabled.

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/ssl-howto.html says if you get this error: A likely explanation is that Tomcat cannot find the alias for the server key within the specified keystore. Check that the correct keystoreFile and keyAlias are specified in the <Connector> element in the Tomcat configuration file. REMINDER - keyAlias values may be case sensitive!

Comment: @Ansari *May be* case sensitive. It is implementation-dependent. In the case of JKS it is case-insensitive.

Comment: Is the keystone password "changeit"?